# Pandas: remove multiple rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is a subset of a `pandas` `dataframe` I have and I am trying to remove multiple rows based on some conditions.

```
  code1 code2 grp1 grp2  dist_km
0  M001  M002  AAA  AAA      112
1  M001  M003  AAA  IHH      275
2  M002  M005  AAA  XXY      150
3  M002  M004  AAA  AAA       65
4  M003  M443  IHH  GRR       50
5  M003  M667  IHH  IHH      647
6  M003  M664  IHH  FFG      336
```

So I would only like to keep the rows where `grp1` is the same as `grp2` for each `code1` but only where `dist_km` is the smallest value for that specific `code1`.

For the example above, only these rows will remain:

```
  code1 code2 grp1 grp2  dist_km
0  M001  M002  AAA  AAA      112
3  M002  M004  AAA  AAA       65
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't `M003  M667  IHH  IHH  647` also be in your desired df?

Comment: Please clarify your question. There are 3 rows where grp1==grp2 and none have the same code1.

Comment: No, for `M003`, the smallest `dist_km` is `50` and since `grp1` and `grp2` for that row is not equal, all the rows for `M003` need to be dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two conditions

```
df.loc[(df['dist_km'] == df.groupby('code1')['dist_km'].transform('min')) & (df['grp1'] == df['grp2'])]

    code1   code2   grp1    grp2    dist_km
0   M001    M002    AAA     AAA     112
3   M002    M004    AAA     AAA     65
```

Comment: You can using query for filter after transform

Comment: @W-B, I somehow haven't caught on with query much. Is there a performance difference?

Comment: At least shorter your code :-)  also https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html

Answer (score 5):

No need `groupby` using `sort_values` with `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('dist_km').drop_duplicates('code1').query('grp1==grp2')
  code1 code2 grp1 grp2  dist_km
3  M002  M004  AAA  AAA       65
0  M001  M002  AAA  AAA      112
```

Answer (score 2):

If creating temporary dataframe is not issue then, you can try using `transform`:

```
tmp = df[df.groupby('code1')['dist_km'].transform('min') == df['dist_km']]
df1 = tmp[tmp['grp1'] == tmp['grp2']]
```

Or you can also try:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby('code1')['dist_km'].idxmin()][df['grp1']==df['grp2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that this could work by chaining a bunch of conditions. I've commented them all to make it clear at each step (the order matters):

```py
codes = df.code1.unique()     # gets unique codes
splitdfs = []

for code in codes:
    tempdf = df[df.code1 == code]                            # select all code1
    tempdf = tempdf[tempdf.dist_km == tempdf.dist_km.min()]  # select dist_km is min
    tempdf = tempdf[tempdf.grp1 == tempdf.grp2]              # select grp1 == grp2 (must be AFTER selecting lowest dist_km)

    splitdfs.append(tempdf)


selectdf = pd.concat(splitdfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filtering your dataframe, applying a groupby/agg and then merge back.

```py
result_df = df.loc[df.grp1 == df.grp2].groupby('code1').agg({'dist_km': min})
df = pd.merge(df, result_df, how='inner', 
              left_on=['code1', 'dist_km'], right_on=['code1', 'dist_km'])
```